# Doesn't executor service in java submits tasks parallelly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was playing with java multithreading code. I created a executor service with fixed thread pool. I am submitting two tasks sequentially. I tried to make the first task really long with the Thread.sleep. I was thinking these two tasks will run parallelly. However, when I run the program, the programs waits for sometime, then prints A B, means the compiler finished the first task at first before going to the second task. Actually, I was expecting, as the second task is a short task, it would be complete before the first task. Any explanation please?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    executor.submit(() -> {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            map.put("boo", "mar");
            System.out.println("A");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    });

    executor.submit(() -> {
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            map.put("foo", "bar");
            System.out.println("B");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    });

    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are "locking" the `writeLock` BEFORE the first thread sleeps.. so the lock is actually locked for 10 seconds.. then it is unlocked. The second thread was waiting for 10 seconds to acquire the lock.

Sequence of events:

```
Thread 1: Starts
Thread 2: Starts

Thread 1: Acquire Lock and wait for 10 seconds.
Thread 2: Try to acquire lock (ends up waiting 10 seconds because it is already acquired by Thread 1).

Thread 1: Prints Data.
Thread 1: Unlocks lock.

Thread 2: Acquires lock.
Thread 2: Prints data.
Thread 2: Unlocks lock.
```

Try something like the below (it acquires the lock only when necessary.. IE: When doing a write operation or modification of the map):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);

                lock.writeLock().lock();
                map.put("boo", "mar");
                lock.writeLock().unlock();

                System.out.println("A");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);

                lock.writeLock().lock();
                map.put("foo", "bar");
                lock.writeLock().unlock();

                System.out.println("B");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        executor.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon! It was very nice and precise.